# JQuery Accordion Menu - One Button Swipes Over Two Areas?

Tags: jquery, menu, accordion

I want to make a simple accordion menu with only one menu button "closed" on load.  However, once selected, swipes over the "top" section and displays the "bottom" section.

Here's a quick graphic of what I mean: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nheU5.png)

I found several examples.  But they all relied on having the same number of menus as menu items.  For instance, here's the one I like, but i'm not sure how to customize: http://www.stemkoski.com/stupid-simple-jquery-accordion-menu/

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, in your graphic... how do you get back to the "Top Section" once the button has swiped over it?

Comment: You click the button again to "close" it.

Comment: Essentially there are two menu items, with the top section having an invisible menu button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a pre-manufactured accordion plugin I quickly cobbled a prototype together.

See http://jsfiddle.net/rJDZj/1/

Have a look and check whether this is what you want.

Comment: Omg..you are awesome!  That was exactly what I was looking for!  Is there a way I can buy you a beer?

Comment: Hey thanks, but... it's all in a days work for bycicle repairman ;o)